# Caps only keypad

Tags: java, android, capitalization, android-keypad, keypad

I have a bunch of EditTexts, and when the user clicks on these a keypad comes up and the user can enter some text.

I want to make it so that the keypad is all in capital letters (i.e. caps lock permanently on).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using android:inputType = ["textCapCharacters"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) in the EditText tag of your XML file.